# A website-and-app tracking service that can be freely categorized?

Tags: windows, android, time-management, web

My goal is to have a tool similar to RescueTime, but has a different structure of category because [its structure isn't much meaningful to me](http://help.rescuetime.com/discussions/suggestions/6812-making-the-reports-more-meaningful). Currently I use Toggl instead for its flexibility to categorize time entries as I wish.

However, Toggl's tracking feature is deficient comparing to RescueTime, as it requires me to manually control the start/stop button (its Autotracker feature only reminds me to change the category of the new visited website, not automatically change it). I need something that tracks the sites I visit like RescueTime, and categorizes the data like Toggl.

Integrating them via Zapier is not sufficient, since RescueTime doesn't provide the amount of time I spend on each sub-category, only the total in one top-level category:

[image: image description]

Is there a tool that can track what website and app I spent time on and how much, and give me freedom to categorized them, with meaningful charts? Or is there a combination of apps that can give me the final results? I have a Windows PC and an Android to be tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [ManicTime](http://manictime.com/)

It does exactly what I want. Love it for the first sight.

It has an Android app, but I use [Time Meter Time Sheet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rk.timemeter&hl=en) and its exporting to Google Calendar addon, then import the times to ManicTime.